# Better name for filter condition operators?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-usage

I’m developing a data filtering system and am a little confused regarding how to name the condition operators for this system. Which of these cases are preferable (or quite applicable) for filter condition operators?

- [Within/Not within a radius of] vs [Is within/Is not within a radius of]
- [Inside/Not inside polygon] vs [Is/Is not inside polygon]
- [In/Not in branch] vs [Is/Is not in branch]

Typical filter condition example:

> [Geographic Point (Lat/Lng)] [Within a radius of] [1000] [meter(s) from] [1000 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10028, USA]

Comment: Thank you, medica, for text rewriting. My English is a little bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to remove the auxiliary verb *is*, because the typical filter condition example you provided is not a complete sentence, but clear and concise and understandable. Thus, the example doesn't need any more addition like the auxiliary verb *is*.

Moreover, formats like *isInsidePolygon* (called Capital Case Naming Convention) are used in computer programming languages like Java. It is used simply to convey a question whether a thing is such a thing or not. But, here your case is different, so you don't need such auxiliary verbs.

Comment: Thank you very much, Neeraj T, for your very useful and detailed answer, it's realy impressive.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I first time here. Thank you one more time.